# Почему sqlite3 не записывает данные в базу?

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Использую sqlite3 в телеграм боте, он получает данные с команды:

```
if "+ник" in message.text:
        await message.reply('Ваш ник добавлен в базу данных!')
        comments = " ".join(message.text.split()[1:])
        us_id = message.from_user.id
        us_name = message.from_user.first_name
        us_sname = message.from_user.last_name
        username = message.from_user.username
        try:
            cursor.execute(f'UPDATE test SET user_nick = ? WHERE user_id = ?', (comments, message.from_user.id))
        except:
            db_table_val(user_id=us_id, user_name=us_name, user_surname=us_sname, 
username=username, user_nick=comments)
```

Но когда я смотрю в таблицу, то не вижу там в поле user_nick данных, вот таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы делаете update в таблице, а это обновление данных.
Что бы добавить запись, нужно использовать insert.